# Angular Universal page loads twice on SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular9, angular-universal

I don't have any higher level NgIf on my main code ( app.component.html) that would cause a reload.
I'm using transferstate so requests won't be called after SSR sets the answers of the public urls.
I'm using isPlatFormBrowser for JS parts.
I checked SSR on local and its not causing any errors.

But some of my pages are getting reloaded after ssr and one of them is just a static html css page without any logic in the ts file.

any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I think you checked not SSR on local because it should be also reproducable there. Angular universal returns static html first and then dynamically removes the whole page and renders SPA from javascript

Comment: I didnt check not SSR on local and i can reproduce some of ssr errores like using window on my local test with that. and im not sure if something else can cause the problem which isnt visible in ssr error logs? @yurzui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem and i decided to share it with the future viewers.
this problem doesn't happen to pages which have routes to them directly from app-routing and it just happens to pages that have routes with RouterModule.forChild and you can fix it by adding

```
{
   initialNavigation:'enabled'
}
```

to

```
[RouterModule.forRoot([ROUTES],{
    initialNavigation:'enabled'
})]
```

Comment: could you please add the code as an example? I am unable to understand(newb here)

Comment: I just checked I don't have pages that have routes with RouterModule.forChild

Comment: As of now, only enabledBlocking woks, and not enabled anymore, and still doesn't solve the issue

Comment: @AmirEl-Bashary it does work with `enabledBlocking`. Works only if the content is drectly fetch no dependent component. My dependednt componet still loads twice but the home page works fine.